# No permissions for my own project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was in the middle of giving permissions to an account in IAM and in the midst of it all, I suddenly started getting error messages that I don't have permissions. I then refreshed the IAM page and lo and behold it says:

> You don't have sufficient permissions to view this page.

Any idea how I can get permissions for my own project?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you have accidentally removed your own account from the project. I hope you have any other owner of the project so that owner can add you up as an owner of the project again. For which you can follow this [help center article](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting_access_to_team_members).

That said, if you don’t have any other owner of the project then there is no other option available to you rather than to [ask for support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) or raise a customer issue in Google [issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/) to re-grant you the owner of your project again.

I would recommend you to adopt suitable measures from [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/docs/enterprise/best-practices-for-enterprise-organizations) which will help you to avoid such situations in future.